# Missing space after parenthesis in inline text

Tags: listings, parenthesis

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstdefinestyle{General} {
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
    breaklines=true
}

\lstset{style=General}

\begin{document}

\chapter{MyChapter}
\lstinline|(a + b) / c|.
\end{document}
```

This results in

[image]

As you can see the space after the closing parenthesis is missing. This is caused by the `breaklines=true` command. If I would remove it the space is visible. But I need this command. Is there a way to hold the spaces nevertheless?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The class and `\chapter` are not relevant. A minimal example would be

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstdefinestyle{General} {
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
    breaklines=true,
}

\lstset{style=General}

\begin{document}

\lstinline|(a + b) / c|

\end{document}
```

that prints

[image]

Add the `keepspaces` option:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstdefinestyle{General} {
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
    breaklines=true,
    keepspaces,
}

\lstset{style=General}

\begin{document}

\lstinline|(a + b) / c|

\end{document}
```

[image]